# む archaic volitional? Translated as Imperative

Tags: grammar, meaning, verbs

While watching Konosuba I came across following sentence:

「我が真紅の流出もて 白き世界を**覆さん**」

What troubles me is the 「覆さん」. The translation used an imperative here, what fits most of the other spells in the series as well; however I don't know how this ending can be an imperative. 
I've read this post ([Meaning of ぬ added to 連用形 / masu-stem, as in 風立ちぬ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12585/meaning-of-%E3%81%AC-added-to-%E9%80%A3%E7%94%A8%E5%BD%A2-masu-stem-as-in-%E9%A2%A8%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AC/12587#12587)) already and assumed that in above stated sentence the general idea is the same. 
Nevertheless before I start making wrong suggestions I would like to know what grammar works behind 「覆さん」as an imperative (if that is even possible).

Comment: This ～ん comes from the archaic auxiliary む, not ぬ.

Comment: The original Japanese doesn't have to be an imperative for the translator to choose to render it as one since the volitional form doesn't translate well into English and especially because it is in keeping with the imperative style of other spells.

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72064/9831

Comment: Is there any way to „close“ my question? The linked posts are perfect for what I was looking for.