# Do I understand the conjugation 散りぬれど correctly?

Tags: conjugations

I'm trying to make sense of the lyrics to "I'm Nobody" by Showtaro Morikubo, particularly this line:

> Don't know why... 映ろう景色に散りぬれど
> 居場所が無いなら
> 暴いてみろ進化論

I've tried to find an explanation of the 「～ぬれど」 conjugation, but couldn't find a good source in English and so have been trying to understand Google translations of explanations such as [this one from Yahoo! Answers](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13132395843).

Based on that, I think that it comes from the (I assume slightly obscure or obsolete) auxiliary verb 「ぬる」, which implies completing something, and the particle 「ど」 which is a variant of 「けれど」, so the line translates to something like "The reflected scenery scatters all around me, but ...".

Is my understanding correct, or nearly correct, or completely wrong? Is there an English language resource that would help explain this conjugation?

Comment: The linked answer says that 散りぬれど is old Japanese and the modern version is 散ったけれど. See [this related question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12585/meaning-of-%e3%81%ac-added-to-%e9%80%a3%e7%94%a8%e5%bd%a2-masu-stem-as-in-%e9%a2%a8%e7%ab%8b%e3%81%a1%e3%81%ac) for ぬ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

散りぬれど is made of three words:

- 散り: the continuative form of 散る
- ぬれ: the realis form (已然形) of [ぬ, an archaic auxiliary for perfective aspect](https://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009005.htm)
- ど: [an archaic conjunctive meaning "even though"](https://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa010014.htm).

So 散りぬれど means "even though (something) has scattered", or 散ったけれど/散ってしまったが in modern Japanese.

FWIW, に in 景色に is a destination particle, not a subject marker. The sentence basically says something/someone has dissolved *into* the scenery (hence "I'm nobody"). I think [うつろう](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%A7%BB%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86/) here probably means "(ever)changing/fading", although it's usually written 移ろう in kanji.

Comment: Aha, I see! Thank you for the in-depth breakdown of the components and the explanation in context.