# 有無を言わさず・有無を言わさぬ

Tags: meaning, words, parsing

I understand "対立する言葉", in this case 有無, however, I cannot yet grasp these expressions:

> 有無を言わさず, 有無を言わせぬ, 言わさぬ.

The definition according to Weblio is: 相手の好むと好まざるとにかかわらず、物事を強いるさま。承知不承知を度外視して行わせるさま。「有無を言わせず」とも表記する。相手の諾否に関係なく。無理やり。有無を言わせず。

> 有無を言わさず、宣告を下す。
> == He/She was forcibly sentenced (no questions asked)

If I understood correctly, this sentence seems to agree with the definition.

However, some other sentences like:

> 有無を言わさぬ迫力があった。
> 有無を言わさぬ口調だった。
> 有無を言わさぬ物言いだった。

...seem to indicate that 有無を言わさぬ means: unspeakable; indescribable as in "too much".

1. Are my translations correct?
2. Is 有無を言わさず identical to 有無を言わさぬ?
3. Can you provide a few example sentences using 有無を言わさず・有無を言わさぬ

Comment: I wasn't sure what is the core of this question. Could you formulate what you want to know in a couple of sentences?

Answer (score 4):

ず is the continuative form (連用形) of the negative auxiliary ぬ. It follows the pre-nai/irrealis form (未然形). In other words, [ず and ぬ are different conjugations of exactly the same word](https://www.kokugobunpou.com/%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-%E3%81%AC-%E3%82%93/). (Note that when ぬ follows a continuative form, it's a different [auxiliary for perfective aspect](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12585/5010) that conjugates differently.)

The difference between ぬ and ず is simple; ず modifies something adverbially, whereas ぬ modifies something attributively (aka adjectivally) or works as a predicate. So 有無を言わせず is *forcibly* and 有無を言わせぬ is *forcible*, *undoubtable* or *indescribable* depending on the context (literally, "(which) doesn't let [someone] say yes or no").

言わせる (ichidan) and 言わす (godan) are [two causative forms](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/86621/5010) of 言う. They mean the same thing, although 言わせる sounds more common in ordinary speech.

So we have the following combinations:

|  | 連用 (adverbial) | 連体 (attributive) | 終止 (predicative) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **言わす** | 有無を言わさ**ず**(に)働かせる 有無を言わさ**ないで**働かせる | 有無を言わさ**ぬ**迫力 有無を言わさ**ない**迫力 | 彼は有無を言わさ**ぬ**。 彼は有無を言わさ**ない**。 |
| **言わせる** | 有無を言わせ**ず**(に)働かせる 有無を言わせ**ないで**働かせる | 有無を言わせ**ぬ**迫力 有無を言わせ**ない**迫力 | 彼は有無を言わせ**ぬ**。 彼は有無を言わせ**ない**。 |

Related: [What is the difference between the negative forms -ず and -ぬ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/235/5010)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I see them so often that I unconsciously "translate" them in my head without paying much attention, so this really made it clear!